# How to handle different boolean values in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have an existing function that checks if an input variable is defined, and returns true if it is equal to another variable, and returns false otherwise:

```
sub isVar1Valid {
    my ($self, $var1) = @_;
    my $var2 = "someValue";   
    return $var1 && $var1 eq $var2;
}
```

I'm writing unit tests for this function, and the expected output I'm looking for is false. In my unit test, I'm actually testing for `0`. However, my test is failing because the above method is returning `' '`, and that is not equal to `0`.

My unit test looks something like.

```
my $actualOutput = isVar1Valid($input);
is($actualOutput, 0);
```

Should I be testing for `' '` as an expected output in my unit test instead? Or should I be returning `0` in my main function instead?

This is my first time working with Perl, so any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean an empty string (as produced by `''`), not a single space (as produced by `' '`). The empty string is false, but a space is true.

Comment: You're right, I did mean it was returning ``''``, which was the value of ``$var1`` for some test cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$var1` is false, the sub will return the value of `$var1`.

If `$var1` is true, but different than `$var2`, the sub will return a scalar that contains the integer `0`, the floating point number `0` and the empty string.

But I wouldn't check for any of those values explicitly. They're all legit values, and it's too complicated to check for each one.

Instead, you should normalize.

```
is(isVar1Valid($input) ? 1 : 0, 0);
```

Better yet, use `ok` instead of `is`.

```
ok(!isVar1Valid($input));
```

---

By the way, note that the following construct is a little weird:

```
$var1 && $var1 eq $var2
```

The purpose of the first check is probably to avoid an "uninitialized" warning. If so, it would be best to communicate that to the reader by using the following instead:

```
defined($var1) && $var1 eq $var2
```

This is important because the second version isn't equivalent to the second if `$var2` can be false.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing adding the ``defined()`` for my first check. After adding that check, my unit tests are working as expected. :)

Comment: That doesn't mean they're correct. You should still apply one of the fixes I proposed. `perl -e'use Test::More tests => 1; my $var1 = ""; is(defined($var1) && $var1 eq "someValue", 0)'` fails just as badly as `perl -e'use Test::More tests => 1; my $var1 = ""; is($var1 && $var1 eq "someValue", 0)'`